# Why do grid lines in lattice plot cover *some* but not all data points?

Tags: r, lattice, r-grid

I am trying to create a graph using the lattice package in R. I am aware of other existing packages but would like to use lattice if possible.

In order to add errorbars to a grouped xyplot, I adopted Deepayan Sarkars solution which I found [here](http://grokbase.com/t/r/r-help/06665zmv7g/r-error-bars-in-lattice-xyplot-with-groups) (code below).

It works fine unless I try to add gridlines to the plot. The grid lines cover some of the data points but not all of them. Does anybody understand why this is and how it can be avoided? I would like the grid to be drawn in the background.

```
library(lattice)

# prepare sample data -----------------------------------------------
singer.split <- with(singer,
       split(height, voice.part))
singer.ucl <- sapply(singer.split,
         function(x) {
           st <- boxplot.stats(x)
           c(st$stats[3], st$conf)})

singer.ucl <- as.data.frame(t(singer.ucl))
names(singer.ucl) <- c("median", "lower", "upper")
singer.ucl$voice.part <- factor(rownames(singer.ucl),
         levels = rownames(singer.ucl))

singer.ucl$voice=factor(rep(c(1,2),4))
singer.ucl$range=factor(rep(c("Bass","Tenor","Alto","Soprano"),each=2))

# custom panel functions ----------------------------------------------
prepanel.ci <- function(x, y, ly, uy, subscripts, ...) {
  x <- as.numeric(x)
  ly <- as.numeric(ly[subscripts])
  uy <- as.numeric(uy[subscripts])
  list(ylim = range(y, uy, ly, finite = TRUE))}

panel.ci <- function(x, y, ly, uy, subscripts, pch = 16, col.line =
                       'black', ...) {
  x <- as.numeric(x)
  y <- as.numeric(y)
  ly <- as.numeric(ly[subscripts])
  uy <- as.numeric(uy[subscripts])
  panel.abline(v=1:2, col = "black", lwd = 2)
  panel.arrows(x, ly, x, uy, col = col.line,
               length = 0.25, unit = "native",
               angle = 90, code = 3)
  panel.xyplot(x, y, pch = pch, col.line = col.line, ...)}

# plot---------------------------------------------------------------
xyplot(median ~ voice,
       groups=range,
       data=singer.ucl,
       ly = singer.ucl$lower,
       uy = singer.ucl$upper,
       prepanel = prepanel.ci,
       panel = panel.superpose,
       panel.groups = panel.ci,
       type="p", pch = 19)
```

On my machine (macOS, R.3.4.0, lattice_0.20-35), the red point is in front of the black grid line and all other points are being covered:

[image: Red point in front of grid but other points in background]

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Konrad

Comment: When you plot with "groups" you are essentially re-plotting in the same panel and so only the last point gets plotted "in front". There are methods to add details to existing lattice plots: `?llines`, `?update.trellis`

Comment: I tried adding arrows or points after drawing the gridlines, using the layer functions from latticeextra or by adding additional panel.points() calls to the main panel function. None of them seems to solve the issue. If I call panel.abline() after panel.arrows() and panel.xyplot() then the gridlines are covering everything, as expected. I could not make the update() function to work with the plot to cover the gridlines, neither. I'd happily accept a solution using update() or lpoints or similar if it solves the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `+.trellis` function in package:latticeExtra authored by Sarkar and Andrews. It handles all the complex grid calls behind the scenes, as it were. If you make a slight variant of your `panel.ci` function that has the `abline` call commented out, and name it `panel.ci2`,  you can over-write an existing plot-object.

```
library(latticeExtra)  # perhaps need to install first
 my.plot <- xyplot(median ~ voice,
        groups=range,
        data=singer.ucl,
        ly = singer.ucl$lower,
        uy = singer.ucl$upper,
        prepanel = prepanel.ci,
        panel = panel.superpose,
        panel.groups = panel.ci,
        type="p", pch = 19)
 myplot2 <- my.plot + xyplot(median ~ voice,
                                     groups=range,
                                     data=singer.ucl,
                                     ly = singer.ucl$lower,
                                     uy = singer.ucl$upper,

                                     panel = panel.superpose,
                                     panel.groups = panel.ci2,
                                     type="p", pch = 19)
 png(); print( myplot2) ; dev.off()
```

[image]

A note on debugging. I first tried just using `panel.xyplot` in the place that now has `panel.ci2` and only the solid points appeared in front, which made me realize that I needed the arrows in the panel function as well. I think the plot looks a lot better with an `abline`-call using `lty = 3` and `lwd=0.5`.